# Chrome Extension - Update Active Tab Dom From Popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

First off, I've looked around at numerous similar questions but I've not found the correct solution.

I am working on building a simple Chrome Extension that gathers data from a specific website (you have to be on that page to run the extension), displays page specific information in a popup, and then based on the data that is finds on the page, it makes changes to the active tabs DOM.

I have everything working, but no matter what I try, I can not seem to find the correct method to send a simple CSS change back to the active tab.  In this case I'm just trying to update a field to give it a red background to show that it is inaccurate and needs to be adjusted.

I have tried sending back to the background.js file and I have tried sending to the contentscript.js file (both without any luck).  From what I've found across my searches I need to write to the contentscript.js, if I actually want to pass data back (which I do).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, without the actual code the question is off-topic. I can only suggest looking at a working [demo extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:redder).

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-insertCSS

Comment: Thanks, regularjoe.  That might be what I'm looking for. :)